# Dart: Use regexp to remove whitespaces from string

Tags: regex, dart, whitespace

I am attempting to remove all white spaces from a string using Dart and Regexp. Given the following string: "test test1 test2" I would want to get: "testtest1test2". I have read some examples in javascript but they do not seem to work in Dart. These are some attempts so far:

```
print("test test1 test2".replaceAll(new RegExp(r"/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g"), ""));
print("test test1 test2".replaceAll(new RegExp(r"/\s+\b|\b\s/ig"), ""));
```

This is based off: [Regex to remove whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736950/regex-to-remove-whitespaces)

Can someone advise where I am going wrong with this.

Comment: I think if you simply want to remove all whitespace it should be:

    print("test test1 test2".replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+"), ""));

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this covers more bases:
`textWithWhitespace.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s|\s|\b"), "")`

The current accepted answer was not working for me. In the case where it was all whitespace, my whitespace was not removed

```
String whitespace = "    ";
print(whitespace.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s\b|\b\s"), "").length);
//length is 4 here
```

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't believe that it was so complex to simply remove whitespaces from a string. So I came up with this solution, which I like much more than playing with regex:

```
myString.split(" ").join("");
```

Comment: This removes spaces and not all whitespaces. It may also be a costly performance wise, although I have not given it a fair testing.

Answer (score 4):

```
print("test test1 test2".replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s"), ""));
```

(without `/ig`) worked for me.
These options are not supported in Dart this way.

- `/g` is equivalent to `All` in `replaceAll`
- `/i` is equivalent to `new RegExp(r"...", caseSensitive: false)`

Comment: Thanks - that explains what I was doing wrong! I see this works just for single space gaps - do you know what I should add to make it work for varying length space gaps? e.g. "test      test1  test2"

Comment: I assume what sniperd posted below your question should do what you want.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer check this.. this is not work this is not work.. try this one `String name = '4 ever 1 k g @@ @'; print(name.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s"), ""));`

Answer (score 4):

This works fine even without using RegExp:

```
myString.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
str.replaceAll(new RegExp("[ \n\t\r\f]"), '');
```

This removes all whitespace (\t \r \n \f) which matches a space, a tab, a carriage return, a line feed or a form feed as seen here [https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#:~:text=%5Cs%5Cd%20matches%20a%20whitespace,latter%20matches%201%20(one)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#:%7E:text=%5Cs%5Cd%20matches%20a%20whitespace,latter%20matches%201%20(one))

```
String s1 = " have Yourself \n \t A M e r\r \r \f r   y  Little Christma s    ";
print(s1.replaceAll(new RegExp("[ \n\t\r\f]"), '')); 
//haveYourselfAMerryLittleChristmas
```

The second example demonstrates that a string which is all whitespace has length zero after applying the replaceAll.

```
String whiteSpacesOnly = "   \t \n \r \f";
print(whiteSpacesOnly.replaceAll(new RegExp("[ \n\t\r\f]"), '').length); 
//0
```

Answer (score 1):

whitespace.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\ "), "");
This is ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

**This isn't an exact answer to the question. However, it's the answer I needed when I stumbled upon this problem earlier today.**

The following code converts a `String` with random spaces (even multiple spaces) all throughout it to a `String` that only has *single* spaces between each word (it removes spaces on the outsides too).

For example, this could be good for when your user chooses a username for your application and decides to be a goof and enters `"  Mr  Bob Felix    Johnson     "` instead of `"Mr Bob Felix Johnson"`.

```
void main() {
  // INPUT NAME WITH UNWANTED SPACES
  String text = '  Mr  Bob Felix    Johnson     ';
  // INPUT NAME WITH UNWANTED SPACES
  final pattern = RegExp('\\s+');
  text = text.replaceAll(pattern, ' ');
  if (text[0] == ' ') {
    text = text.substring(1, text.length);
  }
  if (text[text.length - 1] == ' ') {
    text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
  }
  // NAME WITH REMOVED SPACES
  print(text); // THIS PRINTS "Mr Bob Felix Johnson"
  // NAME WITH REMOVED SPACES
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Matthew Trent's solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67396167/12411655

Instead of this

```
if (text[0] == ' ') {
    text = text.substring(1, text.length);
  }
  if (text[text.length - 1] == ' ') {
    text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
  }
```

you can just use trim() method like this

```
text.trim().replaceAll(RegExp('\\s+'), ' ');
```

Answer (score -2):

mysecond = myString.trim() works for me :)

Comment: This will only remove preceding and trailing whitespaces though. Not anything in the middle of the string