# How to remove all whitespace of a string in Dart?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, whitespace

Using `trim()` to eliminate white space in Dart and it doesn't work. 
What am I doing wrong or is there an alternative?

```
       String product = "COCA COLA";

       print('Product id is: ${product.trim()}');
```

Console prints: `Product id is: COCA COLA`

Comment: Looks correct to me. What are you expecting it to print?

Comment: "COCA COLA" trimmed is "COCA COLA", no?

Comment: the outcome should be COCACOLA, with no spaces

Comment: trim() removes the spaces from beginning and end of string. It doesn't effect the spaces within.

Comment: Look string.replaceAll.

Comment: what should I use instead then?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try this

```
String product = "COCA COLA";
debugPrint('Product id is: ${product.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s"), "")}');
```

Update:

```
String name = '4 ever 1 k g @@ @';
debugPrint(name.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\s+"), ""));
```

Another easy solution:

```
String name = '4 ever 1 k g @@ @';
debugPrint(name.replaceAll(' ', ''));
```

Comment: Do not worry, it's a pleasure

Comment: this is not work.. try this one `String name = '4 ever 1 k g @@ @';
  print(name.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s"), ""));`

Comment: @Fobos white space not removed , plz share other RegExp

Comment: @FurkanVijapura try this:  String name = '4 ever 1 k g @@ @';   print(name.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+"), ""));

Comment: So.. should go with the update one? what is the difference?

Answer (score 90):

This would solve your problem

```
String name = "COCA COLA";
print(name.replaceAll(' ', ''));
```

Comment: How remove different occurence in same string? Like my string is  "hello%25sachin%20here " , I wanti ti remove '%25' and '%20" both ......

Answer (score 11):

the Trim method just remove the leading and trailing. Use Regexp instide:
Here is an example:
[Dart: Use regexp to remove whitespaces from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865989/dart-use-regexp-to-remove-whitespaces-from-string?rq=1)

Answer (score 9):

I know that this question has pretty good answers, but I want to show a fancy way to remove all whitespace in a string. I actually thought that Dart should've had a built-in method to handle this, so I created the following extension for String class:

```
extension ExtendedString on String {
  /// The string without any whitespace.
  String removeAllWhitespace() {
    // Remove all white space.
    return this.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\s+"), "");
  }
}
```

Now, you can use it in a very simple and neat way:

```
String product = "COCA COLA";
print('Product id is: ${product.removeAllWhitespace()}');
```

Answer (score 6):

`var s = "Coca Cola"; s.replaceAll(' ','');`

Comment: First off, `s` is unchanged after this runs. Second, even if this did work, does this really add anything over the top answer?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
String product = "COCA COLA";

print(product.split(" ").join(""));   // COCACOLA
```

Answer (score 3):

In case this is of any help to someone in the future, for convenience you can define an extension method to the String class:

```dart
extension StringExtensions on String {
  String removeWhitespace() {
    return this.replaceAll(' ', '');
  }
}
```

This can be called like `product.removeWhiteSpace()` I've used it in the past to create a helper method when sorting lists by a string whilst ignoring case and whitespace

```dart
extension StringExtensions on String {
  String toSortable() {
    return this.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are so many ways to do this.

The most obvious one:

```dart
String product = "COCA COLA";
print('Product id is: ${product.replaceAll(' ', '')}');  // COCACOLA
```

With regular function:

```dart
String removeAllWhitespaces(String string) {
  return string.replaceAll(' ', '');
}

String product = "COCA COLA";
print('Product id is: ${removeAllWhitespaces(product)}');  // COCACOLA
```

With extension method:

```dart
extension StringRemoveWhitespace on String { 
String get removeAllWhitespaces => replaceAll(' ', '');  // COCACOLA
}

String product = "COCA COLA";
print('Product id is: ${product.removeAllWhitespaces}');
```

Answer (score -3):

**Use Trim Function**

```
String name = "Stack Overflow";
print(name.trim());
```

Comment: trim just removes spaces at the beginning and at the end of string

Comment: bad answer. I downvoted this because the question is about removing all white spaces including middle ones. trim() only removes leading and tailing whitespaces.

Comment: Trim removes spaces at the end and beginning and not in between