# white space is not removing from string in flutter

Tags: validation, flutter, error-handling, flutter-layout, trim

I have a question about trim function. when I am using trim it's not working. when I am adding white space and then used the trim function but still my validation is true. instead of trim has to remove all white space. Hope you understand the question. thank you in advance.

```
 Widget _buildUserNameField() {
    return EnsureVisibleWhenFocused(
      focusNode: _emailFocusNode,
      child: TudoEmailWidget(
        focusNode: _emailFocusNode,
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
        labelText: AppConstantsValue.appConst['login']['email']['translation'],
        validator: Validators().validateEmail,
        onSaved: (val) => _username = val.trim(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: `trim()` method only remove the leading and trailing spaces. To remove all spaces, you can use a regex, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508321/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-of-a-string-in-dart

Comment: yes i want to remove only trailing spaces

Comment: When i am adding email then i am adding single space then validation is becomes true and it will show an error that invalid email. that's i used trim method to remove space from trail but it won't work

Comment: `onSaved` event is called only when you do a `form.save()`.  If you want to validate the value before submitting the form, just pass the value to you validator this way : `validator: (val) => Validators().validateEmail(val.trim())` and update your `validateEmail` to accept the parameter.

Comment: no i want just to remove blank space from the trail that's it

Comment: class Validators {

  String validateEmail(String value) {
    String pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (value.length == 0) {
      return "Email is Required";
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return "Invalid Email";
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

THis is my validator class how can i update as per you suggestion??

Comment: To remove only trailing spaces use the [trimRight()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/String/trimRight.html) function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200142/discussion-between-rutvik-gumasana-and-yann39).

Comment: But it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onSaved` event is called only when you save the form (call to `form.save()`).

If you want to validate the value before submitting the form, just pass the value to you validator this way :

```
validator: (val) => Validators().validateEmail(val)
```

and update your `validateEmail` to accept the parameter.

Also if you want to remove only trailing spaces use the [trimRight()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/String/trimRight.html) function.

As an example, this work perfectly on my side :

```dart
class Validators {
  static String validateEmail(String value) {
    String pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (value == null || value.length <= 0) {
      return "Email is Required";
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return "Invalid Email";
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

```dart
TextFormField(
  maxLines: 1,
  inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(128)],
  validator: (val) => Validators.validateEmail(val.trimRight()),
  onSaved: (val) => _currMember.email = val,
  initialValue: _currMember.email,
),
```

Comment: This RegExp adequately checks for spaces in the supplied (i.e. input) email string. Two thumbs up from me !

Comment:  I think I took it from this community answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/1274485