# How to remove whitespace within in a string in Flutter / dart and capitalize first letter of each word

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to remove white space within a string like extra spaces in between the words. I have tried `trim()` method. but it only removes the leading and trailing whitespace I want to remove the spaces in between the string and I want to convert the first letter of the each word to capital .
example : `var name = ' Aneesh     devala   '` to `Aneesh Devala`

I have tried [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508321/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-of-a-string-in-dart) but it's not suitable for mine.

Comment: Maybe the answer to your *questions* would be the result of a combination of multiple answers. Perhaps you could use that answer you linked with another question's answer about how to capitalize each word in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code will work for you.

```
String getCapitalizedName(String name) {
final names = name.split(' ');
String finalName = '';
for (var n in names) {
  n.trim();
  if (n.isNotEmpty) {
    finalName += '${n[0].toUpperCase()}${n.substring(1)} ';
  }
}
return finalName.trim();}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can capitalize each word of a string by define the capitalize() method.

```
extension StringExtensions on String {
  String capitalize() {
    return '${this[0].toUpperCase()}${substring(1)}';
  }
}
```

how to use?

```
String myString = 'capitalized the first letter of every word the string';
String capitalizedString = myString.split(' ').map((word) => word.capitalize()).join(' ');
```

code example :

```
class CapitalizeText extends StatefulWidget {
  const CapitalizeText({super.key});

  @override
  State<CapitalizeText> createState() => _CapitalizeTextState();
}

class _CapitalizeTextState extends State<CapitalizeText> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    String myString = 'capitalized the first letter of every word the string';
    String capitalizedString =
        myString.split(' ').map((word) => word.capitalize()).join(' ');

    return Scaffold(
      body: Text(
        'Capitalized String - $capitalizedString',
        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w200, fontSize: 20),
      ),
    );
  }
}

extension StringExtensions on String {
  String capitalize() {
    return '${this[0].toUpperCase()}${substring(1)}';
  }
}
```